# How to solve AttributeError: module 'uhd' has no attribute 'usrp'

Tags: python, usrp, uhd

I know it is a wide answered question, however, I could solve it. When I'm trying to execute the command

```
usrp = uhd.usrp.MultiUSRP()
```

from `https://pysdr.org/content/usrp.html` I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'uhd' has no attribute 'usrp'
```

I've executed:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/"
```

Inside lib I have:

```
/use/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages$ ls
uhd usrp_mpm
```

Inside uhd there are the following files (including usrp):

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uhd$ ls
chdr.py     imgbuilder                               property_tree.py  usrp
dsp         __init__.py                              rfnoc.py          usrpctl
filters.py  libpyuhd.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  types.py          utils
```

And inside usrp:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uhd/usrp$ ls
cal  __init__.py  libtypes.py  multi_usrp.py
```

The version of python is:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

The SO is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Anything missing?

Comment: Your screenshot is barely readable. Please post text as _formatted text_, not screenshots.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thank you for your comment, I've changed the screenshot into text, however, the image was readable. I appreciate your help

Comment: Have you tried looking _inside_ the `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uhd` dir and see if `usrp` is there?

Comment: yes, there is usrp (and content within it). I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you, but now what I have found is the Python path issue.

Open bashrc file in the terminal :

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

At the end of the file, add up the UHD path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sitepackages/:$PYTHONPATH
```

Save and close bashrc file, back to the terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then restart your host and test:

```
import uhd.usrp
```

Answer (score 0):

For my install, it was being funny that the UHD library wasn't installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages, but was in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages.
I'm not an expert in the land of python and env variables, so I just copied the library to dist-packages and it works fine

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ -r
```

(prepares for a barrage of "you shouldn't do that.." comments)